# jquery serialize question

Tags: jquery, serialization

Is there something else I can use on a form to get all the elements and their values that won't put them into URL notation? Or is there a quick way to clean up the string returned?

I'm getting this returned:

filePath=afile.doc&fileTitle=A+File&fileDescription=This+should+be+first+in+an+asc+sort%2C+last+in+a+desc

and would need to clean up the URL stuff for a database submission - (the "+" symbol nad %2C (comma).

Is there a simple way to reverse standard URL-encoded notation?

Comment: Matters what environment you are using? PHP,ASP.net etc...

Comment: What do you want to reverse this URL-encoded data to? If you control the server-side code, it'd be better to return this data as a JSON string, which can be very easily turned into an object in JS.

Comment: @Hans Just a simple string. This is for when a user is editing data (which is displayed in tabular format). They click an edit button and the data is displayed in a form, when the submit button is clicked I need to validate first so I used serialize to get all the data into a string. But I don't need it url encoded. Does that help?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is there something else I can use on a form to get all the elements and their values that won't put them into URL notation?

Yes, you can use jQuery's [`serializeArray`](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/), which will *"...Encode a set of form elements as an array of names and values."* This would be best, as you avoid doing the encoding in the first place (I take it you want to work with the unencoded version of the values).

Example:

```
var a, index, entry;
a = $("#theForm").serializeArray();
for (index = 0; index < a.length; ++index) {
  entry = a[index];
  display("a[" + index + "]: " + entry.name + "=" + entry.value);
}
```

[Live copy](http://jsbin.com/olomo4)

> Is there a simple way to reverse standard URL-encoded notation?

Yes. Individual encoded values can be decoded using [`decodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent); a full string of fields can be decoded with [`decodeURI`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURI).

Comment: @PruitIgoe: Good deal, glad that helped.

Answer (score 1):

if you use post instead of query you can name your elements into an array

```
<input type="hidden" name="block[369][filepath]" value="somepath"/>
<input type="hidden" name="block[369][title]" value="somefile.gif"/>
<input type="hidden" name="block[369][description]" value="imagefile"/>
```

I'm kind of assuming allot here but this is how I put things into an array for php parsing so I don't have to rely on jQuery to serialize

just an idea

Answer (score 0):

I think you could decode your URL with your server side language, in php for example string urldecode ( string $str );